# How do we recover a deleted page in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I created several pages with Orchard CMS 1.10.  I accidently deleted a single page today. But to my surprise I cannot find a recycling bin to recover my page from. How can administrators recover deleted files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable "Recycle Bin" module. Otherwise, you need to go back to database.

Comment: Thank you so much.  After enabling the module, I now see the deleted items under Audit Trail.